# Is there a good way to search for all special livery flight or widebody aircrafts from an airport

Tags: livery, plane-spotting

As a planespotter, I want to search for a list of widebody or special livery flights that depart an airport on a certain date. Is there a quick way for me to search for such stuff?

Comment: I found a couple of tools like airgeek.link and JetTip